# Thread que contém componentes de conexão com o banco de dados gera exceção quando os mesmos são liberados da memória

Tags: delphi, thread, multithreading, delphi-6

Precisei adicionar algumas threads para realizar certos processos em segundo plano.
Essa thread faz acesso à métodos de um WebService e também efetua operações no banco de dados.

Eu crio todos os objetos que preciso utilizar nessa thread dentro dela mesma para evitar acesso concorrente com componentes fora dela. Como o `IBDatabase` e o `IBTransaction` (uso componentes IBX).

Então minha thread está mais ou menos assim:

```delphi
TThreadAtualizarDados = class(TThread)
private
  FIBDatabase: TIBDatabase;
  FIBTransaction: TIBTransaction;      
public
  constructor Create(AIBDatabase: TIBDatabase); reintroduce;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure Execute; override;    
end;
```

Como disse, tudo que preciso utilizar na thread eu instâncio nela mesma.

```delphi
constructor TThreadAtualizarDados.Create(AIBDatabase: TIBDatabase);
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate := true;

  // conexão com o banco de dados
  FIBDatabase := TIBDatabase.Create(nil);
  FIBDatabase.LoginPrompt := false;
  FIBDatabase.DatabaseName := AIBDatabase.DatabaseName;
  FIBDatabase.Params.Text := AIBDatabase.Params.Text;

  // controle transacional
  FIBTransaction := TIBTransaction.Create(nil);
  FIBTransaction.DefaultDatabase := FIBDatabase;

  FIBDatabase.DefaultTransaction := FIBTransaction;
end;
```

Os processos que desejo que ela efetue são realizados com sucesso até sua execução terminar.

```delphi
destructor TThreadAtualizarDados.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  if FIBTransaction.Active then
    FIBTransaction.Commit;

  // Comentados porque está causando erro
  //
  // FIBDatabase.Free;  
  // FIBTransaction.Free;
end;
```

As linhas que finalizam a conexão e a transação estão comentadas porque se elas forem executadas, um determinado tempo depois (pequeno tempo) após a finalização da thread (saída do método `Destroy`) é gerado um erro.

Mensagem do erro:

> Programa.exe faulted with message: 'application-defined exception (code 0xc000041d) at 0x77071a91'.

O que não caracteriza um ***Access Violation***.

**O que pode estar causando esse erro, e o que fazer para solucionar?**

---

### Adicionando mais informações:

A thread é instânciada dessa forma:

```delphi
procedure TFrmAtualizaDados.p_Iniciar_Atualizacao;
begin
  TThreadAtualizarDados.Create(Dm.IdbIntsys);
end;
```

Ou seja, nenhum tratamento externo é feito na thread. Não estou passando a referência dela para nenhuma variável de forma que eu pudesse estar finalizando ela manualmente, ou qualquer outra coisa. Já que setei o parâmetro dela para executar assim que instânciada `inherited Create(false);` e mandei ela se destruir automaticamente após finalizar seu método `Execute`, com o `FreeOnTerminate := true;`, então apenas instâncio passando os parâmetros e deixo que ela trabalhe.

Inclusive, tenho até outras classes na thread que instâncio, como `TStringList` e `TList` que não dão problemas, somente as instâncias dos componentes do banco de dados geram problemas caso sejam liberados da memória (`.Free`).

---

Um outro detalhe é que a mensagem de erro é disparada apenas quando troco da aplicação para o Delphi, em modo ***debug***.

Claro que a opção "***Stop on Delphi Exceptions***", em "***Debuger Options***", está habilitada.

Comment: Pode postar o código que invoca as threads? Veja que setando `FreeOnTerminate := true;` o `destroy` já será automaticamente invocado ao término do método `Execute`. Ou seja: se você estiver invocando o `free` da thread, o código do `destroy` executará duas vezes.

Comment: O design que você fez aí está bem bacana. Uma pena não funcionar. Pior é a escassez de documentação sobre estes componentes! Eu acho que você está experimentando mais uma triste limitação do Delphi :-/ Talvez estes componentes simplesmente não consigam trabalhar numa segunda thread, talvez as instâncias compartilhem algum estado que não seja thread safe, talvez eles simplesmente não funcionem se não estiverem colados em um form ou datamodule. Todas estas limitações eu já experimentei em diversos componentes do Delphi. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: Tiago, uma possível solução de contorno seria criar a conexão externamente em um pool e apenas alocá-la para a thread. Um outro teste que eu faria seria liberar primeiro a transacao, setar `FIBDatabase.DefaultTransaction := nil`, depois setar o `FIBDatabase.Connected :=  False` e depois destruir o objeto `FIBDatabase`. Pode me dizer se algum desses testes foi de ajuda?

Comment: Tenta chamar o `destroy` dos objetos com `Synchronize()` para destruir na main thread. Pode ser algum problema com o debugger

Comment: Vou responder então \o/

Comment: Thiago, eu não sei se `TThread` implementa algo no seu destructor que possa afetar o teu código. De maneira geral, é melhor invocar `inherited` só depois do teu próprio código no `destroy`.

Comment: Concordo com @Caffé, inherited deveria ser a última chamada no destructor, inclusive o ctrl+shift+C até deixa um espaço antes para isso, siga a sugestão da IDE

Comment: Thiago, no Destroy o "inherited" tem que ser a última instrução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas vezes, objetos que herdam de `TComponent` tem um comportamento estranho se destruídos dentro de Threads.

Para solucionar este tipo de problema, crie um método para destruir os objetos:

```
procedure TThreadAtualizaDados.DestruirObjetos;
begin
  FIBDatabase.Free;  
  FIBTransaction.Free;
end;
```

E no `Destroy` da thread destruí-los com `Synchronize()`

```
destructor TThreadAtualizarDados.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  if FIBTransaction.Active then
    FIBTransaction.Commit;

  Synchronize(DestruirObjetos);
end;
```

Comment: cc: @TiagoSilva Voltei aqui pra ver se teve solução e fico feliz que teve. Triste é isso: `"comportamento estranho"`, sempre tão presente no Delphi, sempre exigindo soluções que pelo menos a primeira vista funcionam mas que deixam essa cicatriz de código não explicado no nosso sistema. Aparentemente este é um daqueles que comentei: "talvez estes componentes simplesmente não consigam trabalhar numa segunda thread".

Comment: @Caffé A Explicação lógica aqui é que os componentes devem ser destruídos na mesma thread em que foram criados. Como foram criados na Main Thread, devem ser destruídos na Main Thread. Para provar, basta instanciar os componentes no contexto do Execute e remover o Synchronize

Comment: @Caffé Se não for isso, algum outro fator deve estar relacionado a "Thread Safety" desses componentes, "comportamento estranho" é um termo utilizado para descrever algo que desconhecemos.

Comment: @PageNotFound Não tinha pensado por este ângulo, de que o create da thread ocorre em uma thread diferente da execução. Ótima observação e faz todo o sentido. Além disso, faz todo o sentido o ciclo de vida daqueles objetos ser dentro do `Execute`

Comment: @Caffé Sobre o destructor, ele será executado na thread criada pela TThread se estiver com FreeOnTerminate := True. Sobre o comportamento estranho, o que eu quis dizer é falta de conhecimentos técnicos para descobrir se é realmente um bug do componente, ou simplesmente um erro de programação.

Comment: @PageNotFound O Thiago poderia testar e nos dizer (eu não tenho Delphi e não estou certo de que o destructor seja invocado dentro da segunda thread ou depois de ela terminar). Possibilidade de ser algum fator relacionado a "Thread Safety" destes componentes foi exatamente o que disse. A definição que você passou para "comportamento estranho" é bastante óbvia, não creio que alguém pense diferente disso. O ponto é: aceitar comportamento estranho "resolvido" por código que não sabemos explicar o porquê. Havia um tempo que eu aceitava isso nos meus sistemas. Faz muitos anos que não aceito mais.

Comment: @Caffé Quando acontece algo que não consigo explicar, sempre penso que é algo que estou fazendo errado, afinal, existiam/existem excelentes arquitetos de software trabalhando para Borland/Code Gear e agora Embarcadero. Acho que é mais fácil eu errar do que eles. Algumas vezes violamos algumas regras da VCL, de Thread, ou outras e nem percebemos

Comment: @PageNotFound Bacana a informação sobre o comportamento do destructor. A definição de comportamento estranho continua óbvia e não difere do que eu disse: "não sabemos explicar o porquê" :-) E até agora ninguém sugeriu que fosse bug no componente.

Comment: @PageNotFound Bacana o seu comportamento perante problemas no seu software. Este é sem dúvida o correto!

Answer (score 2):

Conforme reportado pelo Tiago Silva, se instanciados, os objetos IB****, dentro do escopo do método Execute o problema não ocorre.
A explicação lógica para isso é que os componentes precisam ser criados e destruídos dentro da mesma `Thread`. Como o método `Create` é executado na Thread Principal (Main Thread), e muito provavelmente as threads estão com `FreeOnTerminate := True` e dessa forma o `destructor` é executado na `Thread` criada pelo objeto TThread, então ocorria o problema.